# Change Request Mapping URL in browser

Tags: java, url-rewriting, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am building a Spring boot project where in all my request mapping URLs will map to respective actions in my Controller classes.

For e.g., I have a feature to visit a page which shows the "Book" details given the "book_id". So the URL looks like this

http://my-site.com/viewBookDetailsById?12345

The above URL maps to the action in my Java code as shown below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewBookDetailsById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

My goal is to change the URL that comes in browser to something meaningful like below.

http://my-site.com/book_name

How can I convert that URL to some other alias URL even though it should hit the same controller method?

Comment: Use URL rewriting for that... Use something like the URL rewriting filter.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example?